# Typescript:: Exporting class and importing it in another application

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a class called TextApi
In my mocha tests I use my class like this..

```
import { TextApi } from '../../../src/textapi'     
   const textapi = new TextApi()
    const getPageHandle = textapi.newPage()
```

So I have a class which is exported in `textapi.ts`like this

```js
export class TextApi
```

`index.ts` is as follows

```
import { TextApi } from './src/textapi'
export {TextApi}
```

Type declaration(`index.d.ts`) is given as

```
export module mytextlib {

    /*~ Write your module's methods and properties in this class */
    class TextApi {
        constructor();
    }
    class searchTextEngine {
        constructor();
    }
}
```

I install my local lib to in another node application like this
`npm i <pathtolocallib>/textLib`
there I import TextApi like this
`import {TextApi} from textlib`
and
try to instantiate TextApi object like this
`const textapi = new TextApi()`
but compiler complains

```
 error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
Type 'typeof import(<path>) has no construct signatures.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as this is my first stab at typescript and javascript world

Comment: Just a tipp but you can directly write `export { TextApi } from './src/textapi'` in your `index.ts`

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's something wrong while you are creating instance from TextApi from textlib.

Here's a TS playground(Error):
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AHArgFwMIHsC2jPwFN5VoBvAWAChpoUAjEAS2GgA8AuaeZbOggJwDcVKjWD4IqfsmCpM-ABQBKMqJrRUAC0YQAdK2gBeaAEZh1aAF8q1ylVCQYAUVZhcIAqov0mLRkjROBBQMHDxCYnM1cXhJaVl5BWDAuADQ3HwiVBUKCxotHV1-EKMuAgB3VJDlcxpbWyogA

Where InputComponent is being instantiated in Example Class and shows error having no construct signatures.

Fixed:
adding typeof in front of

```
constructor(Input: typeof InputComponent) {
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AHArgFwMIHsC2jPwFN5VoBvAWAChpoUAjEAS2GgA8AuaeZbOggJwDcVKjWD4IqfsmCpM-ABQBKMqJrRUAC0YQAdK2gBeaAEZh1aAF8q1ylVCQYAUVZhcIAqov0mLRkjROBBQMHDxCYnM1cXhJaVl5BWDA1ABPRAJMADM4ANDcfCJUFQoLGi0dXX8Qoy4CAHdckOVzGltbKiA

Checkout an interesting article from 2Ality, which demostrate what happens behind the scenes, you will surely find something out
https://2ality.com/2020/04/classes-as-values-typescript.html